# UDK "Error, Accessing a member of _'s within class through a context expression requires explicit 'Outer'"

Tags: unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

I get the following error in the UDK Frontend when I try to make my project:

> C:\UDK\UDK-2010-03\Development\Src\FixIt\Classes\ZInteraction.uc(58) : Error, Accessing a member of GameUISceneClient's within class through a context expression requires explicit 'Outer'

The class `ZInteraction` extends `Interaction`.

Line 58 is: `GetSceneClient().ConsoleCommand("KEYNAME"@Key);`

What is the problem here? I am still investigating and I will update as I find out more.

edit: Tried fixing the line up as `class'UIRoot'.static.GetSceneClient().ConsoleCommand("KEYNAME"@Key);` - no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

From a forum post, [Scripting Changes from UT3](http://forums.epicgames.com/showthread.php?t=706760):

> When accessing a member of a within class' container class, you now have to use the special Outer member variable. This presumably helps deal with name clashes.

I had to change the code to the following:

`GetSceneClient().`**`Outer.Outer.`**`ConsoleCommand("KEYNAME"@Key);`

Depending on what function is giving you this error, you will need one or more sets of `Outer.`. You can research to find out how many layers deep you are, or you can just add one at a time until the code compiles. I chose the latter, because it's hard enough already to navigate this UnrealScript. :)