# UDK "Error, Unrecognized member 'OpenMenu' in class 'GameUISceneClient'"

Tags: unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

Upon compiling, I am getting the following error:

> C:\UDK\UDK-2010-03\Development\Src\FixIt\Classes\ZInteraction.uc(41) : Error, Unrecognized member 'OpenMenu' in class 'GameUISceneClient'

Line 41 is the following:

> GetSceneClient().OpenMenu("ZInterface.ZNLGWindow");

But when I search for OpenMenu, I find that it is indeed defined in GameUISceneClient.uc of the UDK:

> Line 1507: exec function OpenMenu( string MenuPath, optional int PlayerIndex=INDEX_NONE )

It looks like I have everything correct. So what's wrong? Why can't it find the OpenMenu function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the wiki page on [Legacy:Exec Function](http://wiki.beyondunreal.com/Legacy:Exec_Function):

> Exec Functions are functions that a player or user can execute by typing its name in the console. Basically, they provide a way to define new console commands in UnrealScript code.

Okay, so OpenMenu has been converted to a console command. Great. But still, how do I execute it in code? The page doesn't say!

More searching revealed [this odd documentation page](http://www.ohnishi.nuie.nagoya-u.ac.jp/~rjmartin/Tuts/Unreal/Syntax.htm), which contains the answer:

> Now then, there is also a function
>   within class Console called 'bool
>   ConsoleCommand(coerce string s)'. to
>   call your exec'd function,
>   'myFunction' from code, you type:
>
> ```
> * bool isFunctionThere; //optional
>   isFunctionThere = ConsoleCommand("myFunction myArgument");
> ```

So, I replaced my line with the following:

```
GetSceneClient().ConsoleCommand("OpenMenu ZInterface.ZNLGWindow");
```

Now this causes another error which I covered in [my other question+answer a few minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450915/udk-error-accessing-a-member-of-s-within-class-through-a-context-expression-r). But that's it!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your intent, but if you are trying to create a UIScene based on an Archetype that has been created in the UI Editor, you want to do something like this:

```
UIScene openedScene;
UIScene mySceneArchetype;

mySceneArchetype = UIScene'Package.Scene';
GameSceneClient = class'UIRoot'.static.GetSceneClient();

//Open the Scene
if( GameSceneClient != none && MySceneArchetype != none )
    {
        GameSceneClient.OpenScene(mySceneArchetype,LocalPlayer(PlayerOwner.Player), openedScene);
    }
```